# How to run Node And apache together in amazon ec2?

Tags: node.js, apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, reverse-proxy

hi i have an ec2 instance at amazon which runs on normal 80 port and i have a node running on 3002 port how can i make my node run on port 80 in my amazon ec2 instance along with apache i tried most of online tutorials like reverseproxy mod proxy etc on apache

i need to run my node server on www.mywebsite.com/node
now its running on www.mywebsite.com:3002/

i tried to edit my

/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

Of apache like below but had no effect whatsoever

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ProxyRequests off

<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Proxy>

<Location />
    ProxyPass /node http://localhost:3002/
    ProxyPassReverse /node http://localhost:3002/
</Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Why do you need both of them to be running on same port i.e. port 8080

Comment: In my college all other ports other than port 80 or 8080 is blocked so i need to run both in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not used apache for ages now but I think your location for mod_proxy would look like:

```
<Location /node >
    ProxyPass http://localhost:3002/
</Location>
```

Also, have you restarted apache?

`service httpd restart` should do it.

Answer (score 1):

Login Server using SSH

Goto **httpd.conf** file ("/etc/httpd/conf") and edit

```
sudo nano httpd.conf
```

After *ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"* add this line *ProxyPass /api/ http://localhost:3000/*

```
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"
ProxyPass /node/ http://localhost:3000/
```

Now Save the **httpd.conf** file and restart httpd service in SSH

```
sudo systemctl restart httpd
```

Now you run both in same server

> www.mywebsite.com => Apache
>
> www.mywebsite.com/node => Node